# How to relative import the *resource* itself?

Tags: python, file, import, directory

How would I import `config.py` from the current working directory? Why does `import ..config` return the following error: `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`?

```
main_directory
|
|
|--sub_directory
|     |
|     |
|     current_working_directory
|
|
config.py
```

Comment: `import` has no knowledge of directories. It only cares about _packages_. If your code isn't structured as a Python package, relative imports don't apply. If you want to access `config.py` as an independent module with any encompassing package, your only option would be to add `main_directory` to your Python path and then use `import config`.

Comment: I see. So the next obvious step is to learn about python packages I guess. Thank you for your response.

Comment: Fortunately, the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html) is pretty stellar. You may also find these questions helpful: [What's the difference between a Python module and a Python package?](/questions/7948494/) and [Execution of Python code with -m option or not](/questions/22241420/)

Comment: Thanks for recommending the tutorial. It has really helped to understand relative imports in python. Keep up the good work!